# How to use information from the database in the front-end?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query, javascript, api

Can I make a query to the database that returns all my products in Json form? And can I consume that data from my front-end to show what I want or filter it according to what I need?

```
PHP: plugin_dir() . /http/query.php
<?php
    $data = [];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1000

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    global $product;
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $product_data = [
                $sku => '',
                $name => '',
                $price => 

            ];
            $product_data[sku] = $product->get_sku;
            $product_data[name] = $product->get_name;
            $product_data[price] = $product->get_price;
            array_push($data,$product_data);

        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo json_encode($data);
```

---

```
JS
$url: "http://plugin/http/query.php"
   fetch($url)
   .then((data) => {
     return data.json();
   }). then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
   });



foreach product in data: 
   if(product.price => 300) 
     $html = '<h3>' + $product.name + '<h3><br>;

document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = $html
```

---

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do something like that, but I do not know the structure or if I'm breaking a Wordpress rule that I do not know.

Comment: Cragser, a more conventionally accepted way to display data in wordpress would to write a shortcode plugin to display the data where you place the shortcode in the page.   It then runs inside wordpress and has access to all the wp functions to get data out of database.   See https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.  Use  this https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/ to get you started with the structure of the plugin file.

Comment: Supposing the data is from a ecommerce plugin, there's a great chance is available using REST API, which already gives you the data in JSON form.